# send data to JS file without using global variables

Tags: javascript

I need to send data in a HTML page to a script file that is loaded in that page. The simplest way i can think of is to use a global variable which is defined in the page and accessed in the script file.

We all know global state is bad, so i started thinking about the options available for passing data from HTML page to script file without using global state. I cant find (or think of) any.

I am curious whether this is possible. Any ideas?

Comment: Typically, a script loaded in an HTML page is used to access data in the page which loaded it. So pretty much anything in your HTML file is game for being read by your script. What data exactly are your trying to read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. All the javascript scope starts from a global level, therefore you **must** have at least **one** global reference to your data.

Let's say you wanted to store a list of products and events:

```
var myGlobalData = { "products":<products>, "events":<events> };
```

Where `<products>` and `<events>` are two different data blocks.

---

If you're paranoid on global objects, you can simply delete the reference point (thus it's contents) after you finished using it, as follows:

```
delete window.myGlobalData;
```

Answer (score 2):

It really depends what you're doing. In general, I wouldn't advise this methodology, but it's something to consider depending on your circumstances. For the sake of this example, I'll assume you're using jQuery (if not, replace the document.ready with whatever you want to use for onDOMReadyStateChange monitoring).

In the HTML:

```
<script type='text/json-data' id='some_data_set'>
  { 'foo': 'bar', 'baz': 1 }
</script>
```

In the JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
  var myData = JSON.parse($('script#some_data_set').html());
  // YOUR CODE GOES HERE
});
```

Comment: This is definitely an option. I don't see any problems in doing this. Why do you say that you wont advise this methodology?

Comment: Because it introduces an additional level of complexity between your program and it's data. It also means you can't safely use the data before the whole page is loaded. I just use the global variable method in all caps, signifying it's a constant within the context of that page. There's nothing fundamentally flawed with this approach that I know of, however.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to scope your data.  For example, in JS file you can define an object like:

```
   var processor = { 
     function setData(o) { // do stuff
     }  
   };
```

Then in your HTML you know that the data is scoped to the processor.  So you can do something like:

```
processor.setData({someData});
```

Comment: The "processor" is global now. What you are suggesting is using namespaces? jQuery puts everything inside $ and YUI2 in YAHOO. Am I understanding your approach correctly?